# Javascript - Watch for 1st interaction/change on form element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to know how to go about watching for the first change event on a series of form fields/input elements (I have multiple selects/dropdowns and text inputs), and trigger something, but only trigger it once. Not every time an item is changed. And any one of the fields can trigger it.

My situation is I have a services calculator that outputs both a quote for self funding and also estimates which government package level will cover their needs, there's a lot of select input elements/dropdowns and I want any one of these to be able to trigger the event above but only once, (first interaction with the calculator basically) but they are not in a form because we don't need to submit anything, just display the results (this is dynamically updated as fields are changed using `.onchange`). All of this calculation logic is working correctly I don't need help with any of that.

I just want to know how one would approach this with vanilla JS, if at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use event delegation: add an `input` event listener to an element that's a parent of all the `<form>`s (it could be the `document.body`):

```js
let hasRun = false;
document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  if (hasRun) return;
  hasRun = true;
  console.log('Handler running');
});
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <form>
    <select>
      <option>foo</option>
      <option>bar</option>
    </select>
    <input />
  </form>
  <form>
    <select>
      <option>foo</option>
      <option>bar</option>
    </select>
    <input />
  </form>
</div>
```

Or, with the `once` option (warning, not supported in IE):

```js
document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener(
  'input',
    (e) => {
    console.log('Handler running');
  },
  { once: true }
);
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <form>
    <select>
      <option>foo</option>
      <option>bar</option>
    </select>
    <input />
  </form>
  <form>
    <select>
      <option>foo</option>
      <option>bar</option>
    </select>
    <input />
  </form>
</div>
```